# Data recovery formatted disk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs

I have a 1TB HDD with 3 partitions. One of the partitions is/was NTFS formatted. However, I accidentally formatted it on a Mac to HFS+.

I dd the whole disk to an image and ran Photorec on the partition. It did find a lot of files but without filename and without folder structure. I looking to recover photos which I sorted by date via folders. Photos are old digicam photos without proper metadata.

Trying DiskDrill yielded the same results as Photorec. Files without folder structure.

What else can I try to recover the files with the original folder structure. Is it possible to recover the NTFS partition with test disk. I copied the whole disk with dd to a ssd.

Apparently the folders are recoverable because I sent it to a specialist for inspection, unfortunately the price for the recovery would have been more than I could afford.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You could try [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: For file recovery? or partition recovery? I tried it but could find anything. However, I am not sure if I used it correctly

Comment: For partition recovery. The best data recovery tool I tried with a reasonable price is [MiniTool Power Data Recovery](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery-software/pro-for-windows.html), running on Windows, although it has become subscription software (with free trial).

Comment: Leu, after having rescued your stuff "...GetDataBackPro was the program. Works like a charm..." you are still asking the same question again? You recovered your stuff got an extensive answer on cgsecurity.org from and now it's like in "Groundhog Day" on superuser? That is really kind of strange.

Comment: Hi, appreciate you getting in touch with me. However, I have to admit I dont really understand your question/statement. I asked the question here first, what I can do in general to recover my files. Than I asked a test disk specific question on cgsecurity.org. It is true that I received an extensive answer for which I am very grateful, however, I was able to recover my data with a different approach.  I did post my findings on cgsecurity.org as well as on stackexchange so other users may benefit from it. If you have any advice on how to improve my interaction here, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Look, here's someone with exactly the same problem that you have. And he already found a solution:

https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11670

What a coincidence!

Comment: Thanks mate, that was me :)